# Declare DataGridRow event handler with DatagridTemplateColumn design?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I'm looking for the following information: I'd like to declare in the xaml of my datagrid an event handler for DataGridRow element. This way I will be able to distinguish between click onto row with NewItemPlaceHolder item and handle it separately.

But I don't really know how to insert this into following xaml where my datagrid content is defined with DataGridTemplateColumns. Thank you for a hint.

```
<DataGrid [...]>
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="IsEditingTemplate">
                [...]
            </DataTemplate>               
        </DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn [...]>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        [...]
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
[...]
```

Edit : I have found the following, but already have a RowStyle property for my datagrid :

```
RowStyle="{StaticResource DataGridRowSpecialAdresse}"
```

How do I enhance the following code with "and datagrid row default style is XXX"?

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
     <EventSetter Event="MouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="AdressesMouseLeftButtonDown"/>
   </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Comment: can't you add your wanted functionality to the style you have under RowStyle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i understand it , you wanted to add functionality to your already existing  Style for DataGridRow ,
so just create a new style and derive from that using Style's BaseOn property .

```
 <DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}" BaseOn="{StaticResource DataGridRowSpecialAdresse}">
       <EventSetter Event="MouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="AdressesMouseLeftButtonDown"/>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Comment: Since base style is declared in a resource dictionary, I HAVE to extend it in current xaml to be able to add event handler (see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b11113d5-f78d-417c-a8e3-e7d621e571ba/resourcedictionary-and-xclass)